# electron screen sharing via WebRTC - how to establish connection?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, electron

I want to build very simple electron app with screen sharing feature using WebRTC (new stuff for me).

How it works:

- we have two devices - A and B
- device A is sharing it's screen
- device B can see the screen that device A is sharing

My question is: do I need to setup any backend service?
Because I can't find any information about it. Which is weird because somehow the connection between devices must be established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely need some backend service to handle the signalling component (how the two devices share SDP messages, candidates, or other data with each other). WebRTC doesn't specify any signalling, that's up to the implementer.

Once the two devices have negotiated via SDP and shared the candidates, then they can connect directly to each other.